# Why usage of assignment operator or loops discouraged in functional programming?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, imperative-programming, pure-function

If my function meets the two requirements listed below, I believe that the function `Sum` *returns the summation of the items in a list, where item evaluates as true for a given condition*. Doesn't this mean that the function can be classified as *pure*?

**Requirements**

1. For given set of i/p, the same o/p is returned irrespective of when the function is called
2. It does not have any side effects

```cs
    public int Sum(Func<int,bool> predicate, IEnumerable<int> numbers){
        int result = 0;
        foreach(var item in numbers)
            if(predicate(item)) result += item;
        return result;
    }
```

Example : `Sum(x=>x%2==0, new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5...100});`

The reason I ask is that I see , almost everywhere, people advising to avoid the assignment operator and loops because it is characteristic of the imperative programming style.

So, what can go wrong with the above example which makes use of loops and the assignment operator in the context of function programming ?

Comment: _It does not have any side effect_ - it have side effect, when `item` variable mutated in the loop.

Comment: @Fabio ok. But can you elaborate on scope of side effect ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### What is it in functional programming that makes a difference?

Functional programming is by principle *declarative*. You say ***what*** your result is instead of ***how*** to compute it.

Let's take a look at really functional implementation of your snippet. In Haskell it would be:

```
predsum pred numbers = sum (filter pred numbers)
```

Is it clear ***what*** the result is? Quite so, it is sum of the numbers meeting the predicate. ***How*** is it computed? I don't care, ask the compiler.

You could possibly say that using `sum` and `filter` is a trick and it doesn't count. Let implement it without these helpers then (though the best way would be to implement them first).

The "Functional Programming 101" solution that doesn't use `sum` is with recursion:

```
sum pred list = 
    case list of
        [] -> 0
        h:t -> if pred h then h + sum pred t
                         else sum pred t
```

It is still pretty clear ***what*** is the result in terms of single function call. It is either `0`, or `recursive call + h or 0`, depending on `pred h`. Still pretty straighforward, even if the end result is not immediately obvious (though with a little bit of practice this really reads just like a `for` loop).

Compare that to your version:

```
public int Sum(Func<int,bool> predicate, IEnumerable<int> numbers){
    int result = 0;
    foreach(var item in numbers)
        if (predicate(item)) result += item;
    return result;
}
```

What is the result? Oh, I see: single `return` statement, no surprises here: `return result`.

But what is `result`? `int result = 0`? Doesn't seem right. You do something later with that `0`. Ok, you add `item`s to it. And so on.

Of course, for most programmers this is pretty obvious what happens in a simple funciton like this, but add some extra `return` statement or so and it suddenly gets harder to track. All the code is about ***how***, and ***what*** is left for the reader to figure out - **this is clearly a very imperative style**.

#### So, are variables and loops wrong?

No.

There are many things that are much easier explained by them, and many algorithms that require mutable state to be fast. But variables are inherently imperative, explaining ***how*** instead of ***what***, and giving little prediction of what their value may be a few lines later or after a few loop iterations. Loops generally require state to make sense, and so they are inherently imperative as well.

Variables and loops are simply not functional programming.

#### Summary

Contemporarily funcitonal programming is a bit more of style and a useful way of thinking than a paradigm. Strong preference for the pure functions is in this mindset, but it's just a small part actually.

Most widespread languages allow you to use some functional constructs. For example in Python you can choose between:

```
result = 0
for num in numbers:
    if pred(num):
        result += num
return result
```

or

```
return sum(filter(pred, numbers))
```

or

```
return sum(n for n in numbers if pred(n))
```

These functional expressions fit nicely for that kind problems and simply makes code shorter (and [shorter is good](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-best-code-is-no-code-at-all/)). You shouldn't thoughtlessly replace imperative code with them, but when they fit, they are almost always a better choice.

Comment: thx for nice explanation !!

Comment: "many algorithms [...] require mutable state to be fast": Notice that you can often translate a loop with mutable state into a pure, tail-recursive function. I am not arguing that the pure function is easier to understand than the corresponding loop, but I want to point out you don't always need an explicit loop with mutable variables in order to have fast(er) code.

Comment: @Giorgio I was talking about stuff like hashmaps or radix sort. These are useless without mutable arrays, and without them a lot of stuff simply get slower by some `log n` factor at least. There are endless other examples of algorithms and data structures that require big state with O(1) modification and access for optimal performance. Sure, we have tail-recursion that let's us make loops in O(1) memory and this is nice, but there's a lot more.

Comment: @Frax: Sure (that why I wrote "you don't **always** need ..."). I was referring to the sum example. Also many algorithms that build a sequence list can be written as tail-recursive functions and their complexity is linear in the length of the list. Otherwise you are right that certain algorithms are faster if you use destructive updates inside a loop.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal You may find [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/379974/171718) interesting, it nicely captures a tangential concept of establishing truths vs. describing the steps. I also like the phrase "declarative languages contain side effects while imperative languages do not" - usually functional programs has clean and very visible cuts between the stateful code dealing with outside world (or executing some optimized algorithm) and purely functional code.

Comment: @Frax : thanks !! I will look into it. Also recently came across Rich Hickey talk on [Value of values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6BsiVyC1kM&list=PLRZ9CBXkZGmPtdCa8veT_fa5auxuI-BKi) It is really brilliant. I think one thumb rule - "work with values and expression rather than working with something holding value and can change"

Comment: @Frax : Also it is fair to say that FP is an abstraction over imperative programming - because ultimately someone have to instruct machine on "how to do", right ? If yes, then isn't imperative programming have more low level control compared to FP ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Yep, that's right! FP is an abstraction over some ultimately imperative base. I wouldn't necessarily say that imperative programs are always lower level the functional (they may have other abstractions), but that is usually the case.

Comment: @Frax: I would agree with Rahul that imperative is lower level in the sense that it is closer to the underlying machine. If hardware could make copies of data at no cost, we would not need destructive updates to improve efficiency. In this sense, the imperative paradigm is closer to the metal.

Answer (score 10):

The use of mutable state is generally discouraged in functional programming. Loops are discouraged as a consequence, because loops are only useful in combination with mutable state.

The function as a whole is pure, which is great, but the paradigm of functional programming does not only apply at the level of whole functions. You also want to avoid mutable state also at the local level, inside functions. And the reasoning is basically the same: Avoiding mutable state makes the code easier to understand and prevents certain bugs.

In your case, you could write `numbers.Where(predicate).Sum()` which is clearly much simpler. And simpler means less bugs.

Comment: thx !! I think i was missing striking line - _but the paradigm of functional programming does not only apply at the level of whole functions_ But now I am also wondering how to visualize this boundary. Basically from consumer perspective it is pure function but developer who actually wrote this function has not followed pure function guidelines ? confused :(

Comment: @RahulAgarwal: What boundary?

Comment: I am confused in sense if programming paradigm qualifies to be as FP from consumer of functions perspective ? Bcoz if i look at implementation implementation of `Where` in `numbers.Where(predicate).Sum()` - it makes use of `foreach` loop.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal: As a consumer of a function, you don't really care if a function or module  internally uses mutable state as long is it is externally pure.

Answer (score 9):

While you are correct that from an external observer's point of view, your `Sum` function is pure, the internal implementation is clearly not pure - you have state stored in `result` which you repeatedly mutate. One of the reasons to avoid mutable state is because it produces a greater cognitive load on the programmer, which in turn leads to more bugs<sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

While in a simple example like this, the amount of mutable state being stored is probably small enough that it's not going to cause any serious issues, the general principle still applies. A toy example like `Sum` probably isn't the best way to illustrate the advantage of functional programming over imperative - try doing something with a *lot* of mutable state and the advantages may become clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I see previous answers bang on about "mutability" and whether code is "declarative" or not.

I'd put the situation more simply.

Functional languages avoid loops mainly because they have a pre-defined library of methods which operate on arrays of values (I'll call these "array operators"), and which achieve the same effects as loops. Why prefer array operators over loops? Primarily because most loops consist of applying a well-defined algorithm or transformation, and array operators provide a simple way by which these transforms can be called by name. The alternative would be a hand-rolled loop with no explicit name.

As a fallback when there is no relevant array operator, functional languages provide some facility for recursive method calls. There is no point pretending: these are mechanically equivalent to loops.

Why prefer recursion over loops? The primary difference are the rules on variable scope and variable accessibility. Ordinary loops access variables declared outside the block - and the values of these remain available across each iteration and then also beyond the block itself.

With recursion however, the programmer must be explicit about which values are passed between iterations, and which values are returned. There is thus better locality. Although it must be said that the syntax of recursion (in existing languages), is often far less obvious and ergonomic than the typical syntax of loops.

Finally, why is assignment discouraged in functional programming? It isn't - fanatics argue about whether variables are "declared" or "assigned", but any sensible person can see that it's a difference without a distinction.

What is discouraged (or even disallowed) in functional languages is multiple assignment, and thus the reuse of variable names to refer to different values at different times (i.e. at different stages of execution).

In functional languages, only a method call is capable of changing the context where the same variable name can refer to a different value. And when this context changes, *every* variable in scope changes context (and anything preserved between contexts must be explicitly piped across as an argument to the method call).

By contrast, programmers in imperative languages tend to reuse variables extensively, and often in spatiotemporal patterns that are more complex than a Turkish rug. Again, the perceived advantage to single assignment is that it either encourages simplicity in these respects, or that it makes explicit just how complex and subtle the processing actually is.